# How do i make a hierarchical Oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following data:

**structure:**

| id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 1.1 | 1 |
| 1.1.1 | 1.1 |
| 1.1.2 | 1.1 |
| 2 | null |
| 2.1 | 2 |
| 2.1.1 | 2.1 |
| 2.2 | 2 |
| 2.2.1 | 2.2 |

**values:**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1.1 | 10 |
| 1.1.1 | 15 |
| 1.1.2 | 5 |
| 2.1.1 | 20 |
| 2.2.1 | 10 |

i want to bring the following result:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 1.1 | 30 |
| 1.1.1 | 25 |
| 1.1.2 | 5 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 2.1 | 20 |
| 2.1.1 | 20 |
| 2.2 | 10 |
| 2.2.1 | 10 |

i need a oracle query to bring me this result, any idea how to do this?

PS: i know how to solve this problem with subselect, however i need a more efficient way

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Also present your sample data as db fiddle or CTE for instant use.

Comment: I asked a similar question on asktom a couple of years ago. This might put you on the right track: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536677100346820855

Comment: You're looking for CONNECT BY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       SUM( value ) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(s.id) AS id,
         v.value
  FROM   structure s
         LEFT OUTER JOIN structure_values v
         ON ( v.id = s.id )
  WHERE  v.value IS NOT NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR s.id = s.parent_id
)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE structure ( id, parent_id ) AS
SELECT '1',     null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.1',   '1'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.1.1', '1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.1.2', '1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2',     null  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2.1',   '2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2.1.1', '2.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2',   '2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2.1', '2.2' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE structure_values ( id, value ) AS
SELECT '1.1.1', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.1.1', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.1.2',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2.1.1', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2.1', 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | TOTAL |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 30 |
> | 1.1 | 30 |
> | 1.1.1 | 25 |
> | 1.1.2 | 5 |
> | 2 | 30 |
> | 2.1 | 20 |
> | 2.1.1 | 20 |
> | 2.2 | 10 |
> | 2.2.1 | 10 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b997e6dd80976fc84776e379e2c235b7)*

Comment: Such a nice, awesome and smart solution.